# Copying one Array into another using std::copy

Tags: c++, arrays

I am copying a smaller array into a larger in this way

```
int *Arr // this points to array that has size of 7 (i.e) int Arr[7];
int size // this has the size of the above ie. 7
```

Now I want to make a larger array and copy the previous array data so I do this

```
int *nArr = new int[size+1];
```

This is where the problem starts I am trying to copy content using std::copy
I am using C++03 so I dont have access to std::begin and std::end

```
std::copy ( Arr, Arr+size, nArr);
```

The above statement gives me the error

```
Error   1   error C4996: 'std::_Copy_impl': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\xutility 2176
```

Comment: @tmp: Please state the difference between `Arr` and `&Arr[0]`, in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the preprocessor **-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS** in your VS project and the above code would compile.

Comment: I added `D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` to the preprocessor definitions  but I am still getting the same error

Comment: Ideally after adding the MACRO and saving the .sln file and recompiling again should solve your problem.

Comment: @Rajeshwar: You forgot a `-` and a `_`, and randomly added a space. For no reason. Don't do that.

Comment: Looks like my statement `std::copy(Arr, Arr+size, nArr);` was fine. I just needed to disable the warning

Comment: @Rajeshwar: Yes, I said that 43 minutes ago :)

Comment: Agree.. Marked as answer

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Microsoft being picky. Just disable the warning; your code is fine.